# Android kotiln fails to import inner class in abstract class

Tags: android, kotlin, abstract-class, inner-classes, extends

An error occurred when converting the old Java code to kotlin.

To help with the question, I wrote the current problem with the sample code.

```
abstract class AbClass {

      open inner class Test {

      }
}
```

ExClass that inherits AbClass

```
class ExClass : AbClass() {


    private class T : AbClass.Test() {
        //Error AbClass.Test() UnResolved reference: Test
    }

}
```

Why can't I get AbClass.Test ()?

It became like that when converting Java code to Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

AbClass will be like this in Java. When you use keyword `inner` it means the `inner` class can refer to the `outer` class.

```
public abstract class AbClass {
   public class Test {
   }
}
```

When extends AbClass, you declare class `T` without `inner` keyword it means kotlin generates it to `static class`. Basically, `static class` not refer to `outer class` this can be conflict between class `T` and class `Test`. So final if you using the keyword `inner` it should be declared in class `T` too. Make sure it declare same like that

```
class ExClass : AbClass() {
    private inner class T : AbClass.Test() {

    }
}
```